# Does LiveMesh support update of only the deltas of big files?

Tags: windows-live-mesh

How exactly is the update policy of LiveMesh? If i have file, bigger than lets say 500MB, will LiveMesh be able to do only a delta-update of the changes (like DropBox does!) or will it upload the complete file again? This is especially useful, if you want to use encrypted Containers like TrueCrypt.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, currently Live Mesh only does a re-sync. No delta-sync (but it's in the wish-list).

*confirmed from some quick googling*:

- http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/LiveMesh/thread/d50f0562-7bf3-4f47-85e3-83390aceb0a6

*I can totally empathize with your requirement regarding the Truecrypt encrypted folders*